# Access Rails under /app/, not /app/public/

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, .htaccess, fastcgi

I'm trying to deploy Rails 2.1.2 with Apache 2.2.10 and FastCGI (yeah, bad, ancient, ugly, I know). And I know it's no programming question, but please bear with me.

My application can be accessed via `example.com/app/public/`, but I want to access it via `example.com/app/`.

In my .htaccess-File (in the app/-directory!) I have:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /app/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/dispatch.fcgi [QSA,L]
```

How can I forward each request going to `app/` to `app/public/`? Every time I try this (like, with `RewriteRule ^.*$ public/$1 [QSA]`) I get a routing error:

```
No route matches "/app/" with {:method=>:get}
```

Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing passenger either with apache or with nginx is by far, less work than finding the answer to this issue.

And I know it's no exactly an answer, but please bear with me ;)

No, seriously, try: http://www.modrails.com/install.html

Comment: Made me smile :-) But seriously, FastCGI is a hard requirement.

Comment: Finally accepting this answer as it is wise, for sure. I'm not in that company anymore. :-)